# MQTT not receiving message

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, mqtt

I am trying to implement MQTT in my swift application. I am able to connect to Mqtt server

```
[3536:248813] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS_test_mqtt sending PINGREQ
[3536:248813] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS_test_mqtt received PINGRESP
```

I have also subscribed to topics, That also works. but my problem is not receiving any message from server to VC

**App deleget**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

        StartMQTT()

        return true
    }

func StartMQTT() -> Void {
        moscapsule_init()
        //set MQTT client configuration

        let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iOS_test_mqtt", host: "192.168.00.00", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)
        mqttConfig.mqttAuthOpts = MQTTAuthOpts(username: "vqsm", password: "test123#")

        mqttConfig.onPublishCallback = { messageId in
            print("published (msg id=\(messageId)))")
        }

        mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
            print("MQTT Message received: payload=\(mqttMessage.payloadString ?? "no value")")
            let receivedMessage = mqttMessage.payloadString!
            print("from server msg = \(receivedMessage)")
            let data = receivedMessage.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            print("xxxxxxx = \(data)")
        }

        mqttConfig.onSubscribeCallback = { (messageId, grantedQos) in
            NSLog("MQTT subscribed (mid=\(messageId),grantedQos=\(grantedQos))")
        }


        mqttConfig.onPublishCallback = { messageId in
            NSLog("published (mid=\(messageId))")
        }


        mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig, connectImmediately: true)


    }


    func subscribeToTopic() -> Void {
        let hubId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "hubID") as? String
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_id") as? String
        let Topic :String = "/vq/smart/"+hubId!+"/"+userId!+"/rest/octopus/layout/groups/custom/members"

        print("Subring to Topic : \(Topic)")
        mqttClient?.subscribe(Topic, qos: 1)
    }


    func CheckMQTTConnectionStatus() -> Bool {
        print("MQTT Connection Status  : \(String(describing: mqttClient?.isConnected))")
        return (mqttClient?.isConnected)!
    }
```

Comment: I am facing same issue have you fixed this one ?